# Properties matrices's limits

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, limits

Assume that $A \epsilon R^{\ n\ x\ n}$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty} A^k = 0$

Then we want to calculate limit of following expression:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} [(I_n-A)^{-1}-A^{k+1}(I_{n}-A)^{-1}] = (I_{n}-A)^{-1}$$

My question is whether we can freely apply standard rules of limits to limits of matrices.

In this case for instance:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} c\ f(x)=c\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) $$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} A^{k+1}=A\lim_{k\to\infty} A^{k} $$

or
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)+f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)+\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) $$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) $$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} [(I_n-A)^{-1}-A^{k+1}(I_{n}-A)^{-1}] =\lim_{k\to\infty} (I_n-A)^{-1}-\lim_{k\to\infty} A^{k+1}(I_{n}-A)^{-1}= $$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} (I_n-A)^{-1}-[\lim_{k\to\infty} A^{k+1}\lim_{k\to\infty}(I_{n}-A)^{-1}]$$

Comment: As long as the dimension of the matrix is not changing and the limits are well-defined you should be fine. One thing you need to watch out for is commutativity. It is not necessarily the case that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n B^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} B^n A^n$$ for matrices $A$, $B$.